Is there a reliable way to determine if a webpage is generated using MediaWiki?
I wish to fetch raw wikitext from a selection of webpages (which may be generated using MediaWiki or not).
I try to programmically look through the HTML of a webpage, determine if it uses MediaWiki and fetch raw wikitext, else skip. So far it seems MediaWiki pages tend to have:

a <meta> tag with name=generator and content=MediaWiki...
a "Powered by MediaWiki" image in the footer, so look for <img> tag with alt=Powered by MediaWiki

Is this a good approach to look for one of these and try fetching raw wikitext using query param action=raw or is there a better way to do this?
Thanks

If there's a special URL transformation to get to the raw wikitext, just try that, and if it fails to fetch wikitext, scrape the actual page?

@Sebastian Redl I would prefer not to fetch the special url for every single scraped page. The page being a mediawiki page is one of many possible routines in the scraper. It would be best to determine from a combination of url and page html content, the type of the page, and then proceed with transformations.
